# How to concatenate nested arrays in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. In each one of the columns, every element is a numpy array. I want to add a third column which is the concatenation of the arrays in the existing columns.

Say my dataframe is

```
[1,2,3] [4,5,6]

[1,1,1] [2,2,2]

[0,0,0] [1,1,1]
```

I want the new dataframe to be

```
[1,2,3] [4,5,6] [1,2,3,4,5,6]

[1,1,1] [2,2,2] [1,1,1,2,2,2]

[0,0,0] [1,1,1] [0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

My dataframe is very large, so efficiency is important here. For example iterating over the rows and concatenating individually is too slow. On the other hand, something like:

```
df['C'] = list(np.concatenate([df.A.to_list(), df.B.to_list()], axis=1))
```

takes too much memory
(where the df is the dataframe, and it's existing columns are called A and B)

Comment: Arrays is individual dataframe cells is an inefficient data structure - from stoage, manipulation and calculation viewpoint.

Comment: `df['A']+df['B']` how does this work? Also what @hpaulj said. You should try to avoid lists/arrays in a dataframe series

Comment: @hpaulj, This is my input, I can't change that. The question is what is the best way to deal with it. If there is a fast way to transform this input to a different data structure, that could be a part of the solution. BTW, what would you say is a better data structure?